# firefox 4.0 compatible dictionary

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox4

I have written a marathi dictionary that can be found here...

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/marathi-dictionary/

The code is exactly same as any dictionary that can be found here...

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/language-tools/

My Dictionary does not work on 4.0 version while all other dictionary extension mentioned on that page does work with the latest version.
My add-on works with all other earlier version without any problem. On 4.0 it installs but does not show up on right click.

Very confused what is going wrong.

Update:

It seems to use em:unpack. Could that be the reason.